# On APEX 21.2, how to add the pagination of an Interactive Grid to the top left?

Tags: javascript, plsql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex21.2

How can I copy the pagination to the top of an Interactive Grid?

In an Interactive Report this can be done by simply changing a setting in Attributes, but this is missing in an Interactive Grid.

[image: example on what I want to achieve]

Comment: This is not possible out of the box so what you could do is grab the div and move it to where you want it using jquery

Comment: Thanks @KoenLostrie moving the div worked! See the Answer below

Comment: Happy to be of help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment of @KoenLostrie I found a solution to move the footer to the top of the Interactive Grid, above the column headers. Not exactly a copy method, but it will work for now.

The code I used:

On page > Execute when Page Loads:

```
$("#IG-id .a-GV-footer").prependTo("#IG-id .a-IG-contentContainer");
```

On page > CSS Inline:

```
.a-GV-footer {
    position: relative !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

If someone has a solution on how to copy/clone the footer instead of move it, please let me know!